# No post values when using html helpers

Tags: c#, forms, post, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have a problem in mvc3. Im not sure this is specifically mvc3 but, Im currently using that with razor engine. Anyway, the problem that I am facing is, I have a form, I use the TextBoxFor, CheckBoxFor, etc. to render it. The rendering is working flawless, except, when I try to post the data, I basically post an empty form with null values.

Here is my model:

```
public class SendReplyPmForm : PM
{
    public new string Text { get; set; }

    public bool IsOriginalDelete { get; set; }

    public int ReplyNr { get; set; }

    public string ReceiverName { get; set; }
}
```

I have an extra viewmodel layer between the view and the model and it contains an extra paramater regarding this model

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
     public SendReplyPmForm SendReplyPmForm { get; set; }
      ...
```

here is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendReply", "Pm", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formSendMsg" }))
{
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SendReplyPmForm.ReceiverName, new { id = "ReceiverName" })
            <span id="spanChkText">Delete Original Message: @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SendReplyPmForm.IsOriginalDelete, new { id = "chkIsOriginalDelete", value = 1 })</span>

    @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/Forums/Views/Shared/Toolbar.cshtml");}

        <span class="spanLabel">Message</span>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SendReplyPmForm.Text, new { id = "Text", rows = "10", cols = "65" })

    @{Html.RenderPartial("temp.cshtml");}

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SendReplyPmForm.ReplyNr, new { id = "inputReplyNr", value = 0 })

        <input  type="submit" value="Send" />

}
```

and here i have the controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendReply(SendReplyPmForm SendReplyForm) {
       var ViewModel = new IndexViewModel();
       .
       .
       .

        return View("Index", ViewModel);
    }
```

The strange thing is, if I use pure HTML instead of the Html helpers, then the post is going smoothly without any problem.

I read this article ([ASP.NET MVC’s Html Helpers Render the Wrong Value!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx?utm_medium=Twitter&utm_source=Shared)) before I post this, but im not quite sure, that I have the same issue. (f.e.: I dont have action in my controller, that has the same name), but the fact that is also working with pure Html that makes me think.

Do you guys have any idea, how can I use this form with the Html helpers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860065/asp-net-mvc-error-in-httppost-create-null-values-passed-in-model-after-post-m), so you need to add a prefix:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendReply([Bind(Prefix="SendReplyPmForm")]SendReplyPmForm SendReplyForm)
{
  ...
}
```